# Not possible to mount external USB drive using Open Media Vault on a raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4

I want to setup a NAS using a external USB drive  and Open Media Vault(OMV) installed in a raspberry pi 4. For that I'm following one of the many tutorials one can find on the web( In my case this is the one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMpI8csWis ).

I've managed to install OMV on the raspberry and access to it. if I go to the "DISKs" option I can see both my externel USB drive and the micro SD card drive([see Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYf0J.png)) but when I go to "FIle system" option which where im supposed to mount the USB drive, no drive is shown like it is showing the tutorials.([see File_Systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0v8R.png))

Any suggestion why this is happening? how can this be solved?

Thanks in advance

P.S
OMV VERSION is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dpkg -l | grep openmediavault
ii  openmediavault                       6.0.17-1                         all          openmediavault - The open network attached storage solution
ii  openmediavault-flashmemory           6.1                              all          folder2ram plugin for openmediavault
ii  openmediavault-keyring               1.0                              all          GnuPG archive keys of the OpenMediaVault archive
ii  openmediavault-omvextrasorg          6.0.8                            all          OMV-Extras.org Package Repositories for OpenMediaVault
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Answer (score 1):

FInally I found the solution to the issue.
it was just that i had to format the drive for EXT4 file systems and then mount the drive.
In the file systems, there's a  "+ sign" button that give two options when clicked on. these are "create" and "mount" so firtly, I formatted the drive for EXT4 by clicking create and then mounted the drive by clicking mount( see the to picture below)

[image: format]
[image: mount]
Anyway!! hope this helps

Regards